# Open a new Browser Window with JavaScript, not tab, not popup

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to open a new full browser window? not a popup

`window.open(url)` opens a new tab

`window.open(url, "", features)` opens a popup

But can one open a window that can have tabs in it, bookmarks bar, etc?

Comment: This could add a new perspective about user preference in most browser https://stackoverflow.com/a/4907854/707187

Comment: This is well-trodden ground. Short answer: The user has control, not you.